# Is Flux the right solution to get async data to my React.JS views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I am currently designing the architecture of a webapp using React.JS. In React, data flow is unidirectional. Sometimes (often) we want to communicate between views. React solves this problem with flux. So far so good, I now have stores that holds the (shared) data.

Now I wonder if flux is also the right solution for this old problem:
A view, say a table needs data from a server that it should render. I am not that experienced with React therefor pardon me if it's a stupid question, but is flux also the right solution for getting data from a server and parse it to the registered views? If so, is there a best practice to work with async data? If not, what would be an appropriate way to fetch data from the server for a react view?

I actually don't want a view to call for the data. In my opinion a view should be as stupid as possible...

Comment: Perform async actions in action creators and emit actions (messages) with the payload you retrieved from the resource API. That way the rest of your system (stores, components, dispatcher) will be unaware of asynchronicity.

Comment: An example or link to an example would be much appreciated

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EQSQFx5R

Comment: Flux is a way to manage application state; I believe what you are looking for is [Container Components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.d2qzqx1lc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..is flux also the right solution for getting data from a server and
>   parse it to the registered views?

You can do this with flux. Flux is al about [Action Creators](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/actions-and-the-dispatcher.html). In the flux architecture the idea is that you have a [Controller View](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#views-and-controller-views) that registers itself with a [Store](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#stores). The Controller View is your *smart component*, it gets it state from the Store(s) and usually it renders child components, *dumb components*, where it passes (some of) the state as properties to it's child(ren).

[image]

When for instance you're fetching data from a server, you need to trigger an Action Creator, this Action Creator will then call a Web API utility that performs the  actual request. When successful, the Web API utility will call a Server Action Creator that dispatches an action containing the payload received from the server. Any registered Store will then process this action and emit a change event. This way any Controller View interested in a Store, will be notified by it when the Store's data has changed. The Controller View will update it's state and re render itself and any child(ren) to display correct data.

This means that you can call an Action Creator to for instance fetch data from the server in the `componentDidMount` (note that this hook is only executed once though!) method of the Controller View.
Initially the Controller View will ask the store for data and get, for example, an empty array, which will be set as the Controller View's state and the Controller View will render something empty. Then after the data has been fetched, the Controller View (who is notified by the Store) will again retrieve the data from the Store, only now it will not be empty. The Controller View updates it's state accordingly, triggering a re render and displaying the appropriate data.

The essence of this is captured in this minimal (pseudo) code:

```
// Action Creator: actions/data.js
import { fetchData } from '../utils/server';

export function fetch() {
  fetchData();
}

// Server Action Creator: actions/data-server.js
import dispatcher from '../dispatcher';

export function receiveData(data) {
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
    payload: data
  });
}

// Web API Utility: utils/server.js
import request from 'request';
import { receiveData } from '../actions/data-server';

export function fetchData() {
  request.get('https://api.com/v1/data', receiveData);
}

// Store: stores/store.js
import dispatcher from '../dipatcher';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';
let __data__ = [];

const Store = Object.assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  emitChange () {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  addChangeListener (callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  removeChangeListener (callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  getData () {
    return __data__;
  }
});

Store.dispatchToken = dispatcher.register(function (action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RECEIVE_DATA':
      __data__ = action.payload;
      Store.emitChange();
      break;
  }
});

export default Store;

// Controller View: components/List.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Store from '../stores/Store');
import { fetch } from '../actions/data';

var __getState = function () {
  return {
    data: Store.getData()
  };
};

export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return __getState();
  },

  componentWillMount () {
    fetch();
  },

  componentDidMount () {
    Store.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  componentWillUnMount () {
    Store.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  _onChange () {
    this.setState( __getState() );
  },

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="list">
        <ul>
          { data.map(dataItem => <li>{ dataItem.name }</li> )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Check out more detailed flux examples [here](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples).

> I actually don't want a view to call for the data. In my opinion a
>   view should be as stupid as possible...

It's good practice to distinguish between *smart* and *dumb* components. The idea is that smart components hold state and call actions, while the dumb components have no dependencies on the rest of the application. This creates a clear separation of concerns and allows for better reusability and testability of your components. Read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.67u41cy8o).

Also there are some interesting alternatives besides flux. For instance there is [redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux). It uses a single immutable state Object (i.e. Store) where a reducer (pure function) is only allowed to modify application state by means of actions.

And definitely check out [react-refetch](https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch) if you're mostly fecthing and rendering read-only data from a server.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. One last question might be: Is it also possible to ask a store whether there is already data available? Let's say a call to the server takes a lot of time and I don't want to make it each time a view requests it, so the store itself should be aware of some kind of invalidation timestamp of the data. Would it be possible to ask the store for data, not be notified if there are new data?

Comment: @Christian You're welcome. Flux enforces unidirectional data flow, so you shouldn't ask from a Controller View if the Store has any changes, the Store will let the Controller View know (see the diagram). The idea behind keeping flow one way is to keep things simple. But you could keep some sort of flag/value on the Store and have a method on the Store that reads the value, i.e. the same way you get data from the Store in your Controller View. Then if an action is dispatched, the Store could update the value of the flag accordingly. For example indicating a loading state.

Comment: mhm. What happens if I have 2 Views on a page (say it's a dashboard) and both are calling an action: "Hey, get me the data from the server". It would actually be enough to query these data once. I guess this is kind of an implementation detail within the ActionCreator or something which I need to take care of right?
Well question is: How would you prevent querying the same  for each component. A view needs to trigger an acition: "give me data x" but a lot of views could do this the same time and all other views would get the change...

Comment: @Christian If you only need to fetch the data once you could use the `componentWillMount()` hook. Let's say you have `<Dashboard />` and it renders `<A />` and `<B />` which need to show data that is fetched from the server, i.e. two requests one for A and one for B, therefore 2 actions. You could fire the actions to fetch data for A and B in the `componentWillMount()` hook of `<Dashboard />` so it will only fetch data once.

Comment: @Christian  `<Dashboard />`, your Controller View, will then register itself with the Store(s) and set data A and B as state. Also it will render `<A />` and `<B/>` where it passes data A and B as props to the corresponding components. Initially the Store(s) won't have data, but at some point your requests will finish and populate the Store(s) with said data (if everything goes ok). Then it will notify `<Dashboard />` and it will re render , including `<A/ >` and `<B />` with the data.

Comment: @Christian And if your data doesn't change at all, a different strategy could be to "bootstrap" your app. Fetch everything in the beginning, and only render the application when you have all your data.

Comment: sounds nice, but this would break the best thing in React wouldn't it? React knows exactly what to rerender, which data has changed. So for instance, if I collect the data and parse them into <DashboardItem1/> and 2, it enforces both to rerender completely if the state changes. Maybe I don't need a complete rerender because just a small label has changed. So maybe it would be a better solution to trigger this action within <Dashboard/>, initially parse in the data and also listen for changes within the <DashboardItem/> components..

Comment: @Christian I don't understand what you mean. The whole point of doing this is to let react do what is does best, use it's virtual DOM powers. This is what render returns, a virtual DOM Object. When a component's props or state change, React decides whether an actual DOM update is necessary by constructing a new virtual DOM and comparing it to the old one. Only in the case they are not equal the DOM will be reconciled, applying as few mutations as possible. Read more about this [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html).

Comment: @Christian you can optimize by using the `shouldComponentUpdate()` hook (together with [immutablejs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)).   Read more about it [here](http://buildwithreact.com/article/optimizing-with-shouldcomponentupdate).

Answer (score 2):

A common way to do this is to initialize the async call in the view code's componentDidMount() method, and render it properly.

The code might be different for different flux implementations but you get the idea

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    rows: MyStore.getState().rows
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.listenTo(MyStore, this.onChange)
  MyActions.fetchData()
}

onChange() {
  this.setState(this.getInitialState())
}
....


render() {
  if (!this.state.rows) {
    return <span />
  }

  return <Table rows={this.state.rows}>
}
```

As for the container components, it's totally up to you to use it or not.